# How to assign weights in data analysis

Tags: weighted-data

I have a dataset that has a field 'Course' and for each course, there is a varying number of lessons. I am trying to compare the number of quizzes accessed for each of the lessons and group by course but since each course has a varying number of lessons, I can't seem to figure out what would be the best way to compare the courses on the number of quizzes accessed. The higher the number of lessons the greater the probability that the related course is always ranked at the top (since their quizzes would be accessed the most). How can we rank the courses? Say Course_1 has 6 lessons and the quizzes attached to them were accessed by different learners 15 times whereas Course_2 has 3 lessons and the quizzes attached to them were accessed 10 times, how can we compare the two courses?

In statistics what methods are available to analyse such data? I am not applying any machine learning techniques on the data as we are not training any data just trying to compare the dataset

Answer (score 1):

You could divide the number of quizzes accessed by every course by the number of lessons that a course has. This will result in the average quizzes accessed by a lesson of a course and would make it comparable between different courses. For Course_1 this would be 2.5 (15/6) and for Course_2 it would be 3.33 (10/3). You could also calculate the quizzes per course lesson if this is possible to aggregate and then take the course-wide median.